# How to find data between two days BUT excluding the data in the weekends

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I want to find data between two dates (ex. registration of the users for the month of August) but only the data that was registered during the working days, I want to exclude the data from the weekends.

NOTE: I have found similar question on Stac kOverflow but all of them calculate the number of days between two dates excluding the weekends. I want to search data between two dates but only for the working days. I have a timestamp in my data table, but I don't know how to make an SQL query that will recognize if the timestamp is a working day or weekend.

Comment: You tagged mysql and sql-server, please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`dayofweek`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function to exclude weekends:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  register_date BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND '2014-09-01' AND
       DAYOFWEEK(registerdate) NOT IN (1, 7)
```

Note, however, that if you're looking for the users who registered on August, it might be easier to use the [`month`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function instead of the `between` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  MONTH(register_date) = 8 AND
       DAYOFWEEK(registerdate) NOT IN (1, 7)
```

Comment: DATEOFWEEK IS NOT RECOGNISED SO I used DATEPART (DW, timestamp) NOT IN (1, 7). What does NOT IN (1,7) MEAN ???

Comment: `dateofweek` isn't a function - it's `**day**ofweek`, as I wrote (which is, as you noted, just a syntactic sugar on top of `datepart`). The `dayofweek` function returns a numerical representation of which day it in in the week - Sunday is 1 and Saturday is 7. So by excluding them both you'd be excluding the weekend.